# Possible unhandled promise rejection (id:0) React native axios

Tags: json, reactjs, request, native

I found a json data in internet and my app is working but when i copy same json data to my hosting. It doesnt work.
Everything is same just link is different. nCould you help me?

This is working

```
    state = { data: [] };
  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
    .then(response => this.setState({ data: response.data }));
  }
```

This is not working

```
      state = { data: [] };
  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('http://ozandikbas.com/sendingdata2')
    .then(response => this.setState({ data: response.data }));
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAEFR.png)

Comment: Is this on iOS? I think the issue is with setting where it doesn't allow you to request non-secure resources. In your case your server should have https enabled.

Comment: yes this is ios. i didnt try on android. i will.. now i am trying https

Comment: yes you are right. it is https problem. thank you very much :)